# Magento 2 Category Custom attribute doesn't exists error

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg, category-attribute

I have created a module where i have added two custom attribute to category page. Here is my code.

> Setup\InstallDate.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'banner_image',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'backend' => Image::class,
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 5,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'custom_text', 
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Header Banner Text',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'sort_order'   => 10,
                'source'       => '',
                'global'       => 1,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default'      => null,
                'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                'group'        => '',
                'backend'      => ''
            ]
        );

        
    }
    
}
```

and this is my

> category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general" sortOrder="10">
        <field name="banner_image" formElement="imageUploader">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/image</elementTmpl>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Header Banner Image</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <required>false</required>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <imageUploader>
                    <settings>
                        <required>false</required>
                        <uploaderConfig>
                            <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="catalog/category_image/upload"/>
                        </uploaderConfig>
                        <previewTmpl>Magento_Catalog/image-preview</previewTmpl>
                        <openDialogTitle>Media Gallery</openDialogTitle>
                        <initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>catalog/category</initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>
                        <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                        <maxFileSize>4194304</maxFileSize>
                    </settings>
                </imageUploader>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        <field name="banner_text">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Promotion Text</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">promotion_text</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">33</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I wonder, what i'm doing wrong, for wyiswyg editor it always says banner_text attribute doesn't exist.
Any solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Error:** You are type wrong field name. Have a look file `Setup\InstallDate.php` you created new field is `custom_text` but in `category_form.xml` you type is `banner_text`.

**Fix:** So you need change `custom_text` to `banner_text` in `Setup\installDate.php` then login to database change this name in table `eav_attribute`.

Hope it help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hello First of all in category_form.xml change "banner_text" to "custom_text" and than do following command.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```